# Calculate End Date, based on start date and drop down list of number of Package in cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to know if this is possible to calculate an end date based on user picking a start date and a select list of number of package.

i.e. I select a silver package and  choose a start date of 1 Jan - in theory the date field would automatically update with the date that is 30 days later, i.e. 2 February.

Is there a way to do this?

kind information i  have three package  silver   for 30 
                     gold     for 40 
                     platinum for 50

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? custom dates are explained in the component's documentation...

Comment: how can i do this i am new in this cake php any help for me

Comment: Provide your code and/or a demo on jsfiddle; quickly take a look at http://api.jquery.com/change/ for your select and http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate to set a date on your datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in view page 

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
$( "#start_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'

});
$( "#end_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'

});

$('#start_date').bind('change', function() {
 $.ajax({
                sync: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'subscription_id=' + $("#packagename").val() + '&start_date=' + $("#start_date").val(),
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Subhistories', 'action' => 'diff'), true); ?>',
                success: function(e)
                {

                    $('#end_date').val(e);

                }
            });  
            return false;


});
});
</script>
```

create one function in controller likde diff()
{

```
        $save=$this->Subscription->find('first',array('conditions'=> array('subscription_id'=>$_REQUEST['subscription_id'])));
         echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST['start_date'].  ' + ' .$save['Subscription']['no_of_days']. ' days'));
          exit;

        }
```